Lenovo Z50-70 touchpad not working
I also have a Lenovo Z50-70 but I can't use anything. I can't scroll or right click or left click. I can't even tap to click! The only way I can move my pointer and click is by using an external mouse. How can I have my entire touchpad work?
Thank You!
By the way, I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. It works flawlessly on my laptop.
